Who did the end credits music in “Glitch” Korean Netflix TV series?
In Glitch TV series at the end credits of the last episodes (e.g.: "ep08..") of the first season there is some truly hypnotic/mesmerizing/magic electronic music (soundtrack) that plays for approximately 1m36s that not even the Shazam mobile app can identify it
Who made that soundtrack?
Because of the Glitch actors previous works I suspect that could be Mr. Kang Ki-young aka  Dalpalan but I am not sure

Glitch review at IMDb
Sample of the aforementioned soundtrack (click "view raw")


Is there any reason to assume it's not Kang Ki-young? Wikipedia and theMovieDB.org mention he made the music for the series.
